# How to flash between two different sets on LEDs using a 556 Timer IC

Tags: circuit-design

I am planning to create a circuit that would flash between two different sets of LEDs (hopefully at an interval of 30 seconds, but at least above 10 seconds) automatically after a button is pressed once, and repeat afterwards until power is disconnected.

```
               __________________________________________________
Switch _______|
               ___________             ___________            ___     
LEDs A _______|           |___________|           |__________|
                           ___________             __________                 
LEDs B ___________________|           |___________|          |___
```

*Figure 1. Timing diagram.*

The goal is to have the power separate, and press a button once to activate. The button itself would not need to be pressed again until the on/off switch is used.

I am going to use 100uF capacitors, a LM556N Timer IC, a simple on/off switch for the power itself, and a push button to start the process.

The LEDs operate at 3-3.2V, 20mA.
I will use either a 3xAA battery holder (4.5V) or a single 9V battery to supply power.

I am confused about how to swap between the timers and at the same time reset the other. So when one timer starts one set of the LEDs will stay on, and then once that timer is done, it will reset then start the other set of LEDs. These will repeat the same process as before.

The full parts list (Most likely won't change it unless I have them on hand):

100uF capacitors

Resistors (I have many different values so the value itself doesn't matter too much)

LEDs (3-3.2V, 20mA)

LM556N Dual Timer IC

3xAA Battery packs or 9V battery and connector

Simple on/off switches

Push buttons

Some NPN and PNP Transistors, will have to check when I get home.

Breadboard to test, PCBs for final products

Side note: I am not planning to use a microcontroller, mostly because I am planning to produce many of these.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you aiming to flash one set, then the other, then stop, or repeat with them alternating?

Comment: If you want one set to be on continuously for 30 s, the go out while the other set is on continuously for 30 s, then repeat, this can be done with one 555.  However, 30 s is a looong time for a bipolar 555.  A CMOS 555 would be better for this, but it can source only 10 mA.  What is the current for each LED set?

Comment: And, what are the operating voltages for the circuit and the LED sets?

Comment: I want it to repeat while alternating, the time can be anything, but i’d prefer above 10 seconds, and the operating voltage is 9V.

Comment: I originally planned to use a battery holder for 3xAA, which would give me a voltage of 4.5V, but when I looked into it the operating voltage for the IC was 4.5-15 or 4.5-16V, so I was worried about when the batteries reduce in voltage any tiny amount it would make the circuit stop working. Also, the current for the LEDs is 20mA

Comment: Keep forgetting to mention stuff, the LED's voltage varies with the colors, the two colors I am using are 3-3.2V

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't add information in comments otherwise you're expecting people to piece the full question together in their head. Edit the question with the new information. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, will do now.

Comment: Ta. I don't get the switch behaviour clearly, though. Is the sequence...     NO_PRESS:  LEDsA=0  LEDsB=0;   
  PRESS_HOLD: repeat[LEDsA=1  LEDsB=0  wait30secs  LEDsA=0  LEDsB=1  wait30secs]

Comment: Correct, but I would like it to repeat. Edited my question for the button and on/off switch behavior.

Comment: I've added a timing diagram (which is generally worth a pile of words) for you. Please review and edit it if it's not quite right.

Comment: I put 'repeat[' in there :-) Can you just use a push-on-push-off switch, one that you press once to turn on, press again for off, again for on etc? That's done mechanically within the tiny switch and would greatly simplify things. Plus, you wouldn't need a separate power switch. And it would generate the switch waveform in your diagram.

Comment: I would use one, but I'm on a time crunch so I don't have the time to order one.

Comment: Are you expecting the circuit will draw very little current until the momentary switch is pushed? Are you sure you need that as opposed to just having it start when power is applied? It's easy with a microcontroller, but adds some complexity with a 555 sort of circuit, and you'll probably need to add some transistors, so if you need it, tell us what transistors (BJT or MOSFETs) you have available.

Comment: I have NPN and PNP (presumably BJT), edited into the full parts list.

Comment: Pity you can't get other parts. You could build and debug this far, far more easily if you used a 74HCT4060. You'd get your alternating behaviour and it would also work more accurately.

Comment: not with a 4060,  4047 has alternating outputs on the bistable side. in any case alternating with a 555 or 556 is easy.  it's  the soft switch that's tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a circuit online which utilizes one side of the 556 IC to complete the cycle. This circuit (when using a 100uF capacitor instead) changes between the LED sets about every 11 seconds on a simulator. Thanks to everyone for trying to help me.

https://www.petervis.com/GCSE_Design_and_Technology_Electronic_Products/simple-555-circuits/555-timer-dual-led-flasher.html

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a circuit that uses the constrained component set and performs (more-or-less) the requested function. Because of the way the 555 works, the first toggle is about 80 seconds in, and the following transitions follow every 30 seconds with the given components.

[image]

The components in the box on the left simulate a pushbutton conected from E to C on Q1 that is pressed 70ms after the 6VDC power V1 is applied.

Simulation works fine in LTSpice, though the 555 is a CMOS type (despite being called an LM555).

Q1 and Q2 perform the latching power switch from the momentary pushbutton. C3 is a bypass capacitor. C1 and R1 are the timing components, ideally C1 will be a low leakage +/-10% type such as Nichicon UKL series, however in practice just about any normal radial lead non-low-impedance standard electrolytic will work fine.

The 555 switches the LED D1 directly, and the network D3/R7/R5 is necessary because the output voltage can be quite high when sinking significant current, and we wish Q4 to remain off when D1 is on (output low) so either D1 or D2 is on at all times when the switched supply voltage is present.

---

Contrast this with using a microcontroller such as the 8-pin PIC12F675 operating from 4.5V.

Aside from the switch and LEDs, you would need only the microcontroller, one or two resistors and a 100nF bypass capacitor.

Comment: I'm using a LM556, not a LM555, in order to alternate. I'm not planning to use a micro-controller, mostly because it will increase the costs, and also that I am not planning to order anything else now. Editing the question now.

Comment: You don’t have to use both halves of the 556. Using half is the same as an LM555. For producing many, a micro controller is the way to go most likely,

Answer (score -1):

something like this should do it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNXDbH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

unfortunately circuitlab doesn't have a sensible 555 model, so it can't be simulated.

Comment: Now just have to find a 200uF cap with leakage << 1uA

Comment: <1uA at 6v should be possible for any part manufactured in the last 30 years

Comment: not so fast... I ≤ 0.01 CV (µA)  for Tantalum  220uF *6V= 12uA and alum Ⅰ=0.01CV or 3μA whichever is greater

Comment: hmm yean, a 100uF film capacitor would be quite big, and is probably not available and I doubt tohose 100uF capacitors are MLCCs either.

Comment: no problem with MLCC, but big problem with leakage

Comment: put two capactors one to +V and the other to ground so that leakage mostly cancels,  I've used 555s at 30 seconds before with second-hand electrolytics and it worked

Comment: In theory 2 series Caps with 2C does not affect total Q=CV nor the total leakage.  0.01CV  but sometimes you get lucky

Comment: So with something like this, I would essentially just use the two different sides of the 556 timer in place of the two 555 timers, just with a common voltage input and ground, correct?

Comment: yes, use the two sides of the 555 one side as a latch to remember the button press and the other side to run the LEDs

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I mean capacitors in series across the supply rail like in the edit above, that leaks through C1  has the opposite effect of what leaks through c2

Comment: Just for some more information, Tinkercad has a circuit builder and simulator (using the actual look of the component instead) and has a 556 timer, done through a website. This is what I am using to test it. Once I test that it works properly in the simulation I will test on a breadboard.

Comment: Cap choices are poor for long time constants. whereas a CD4060   uses ceramic caps and binary counter then add transistors for inverter/drivers, but the design lacks good specs, so there will be issues

Comment: Would I be able to substitute the ceramic capacitors for an electrolytic one?

Comment: yes if you have ceramic capacitors of around 100uF that would work.

Comment: That’s a BIG “IF”, meaning no

Comment: such devices are available eg TDK C3216X5R0J107M160AB

Comment: The schematic as shown (10:08 pm. EST) will not work as desired.  The LEDs are a "dead" short across the power rails, and will be on continuously with no current limiting.  You want R2 to go to the four upper LEDs, and R3 to the four lower LEDs.